# Issue when packaging to jar (postgresql)

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, heroku, intellij-idea

Code errors as: `No suitable driver found for [link]`

The link works - running it in IntelliJ IDE works fine, but, as a jar file, it doesn't work. Someone suggested, in a previous question, to add maven assembly plugin. I might be doing that wrong, heres the build:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

It creates an error here: `return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);`
The link works perfectly fine - I even created a url by hand, created a test class, and ran that in the IDE. It compiled and I was able to print the connection object. However, once I made it a jar file (build artifacts)
Note: if it matters, the database is made and hosted with Heroku.

[image]

it creates a no suitable driver error. I thought this might be because I entered something wrong in my pom.xml file, so I re-copy-pasted the plugin.
If needed, here is everything (link included since its a test database anyways)

**MAIN CLASS**

```java
package main;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://ec2-50-17-90-177.compute-1.amazonaws.com/d7mfkbl2si37vm?sslmode=require&user=tzfelalpgpknzs&password=99cce506d410d89c1ee51f2f8b35eae9c6faacd4b578c29ff18b5e5de3cfcf98"));
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Database-Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1203-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, turns out I'm stupid.
Did a bit more reading, and decided to switch to maven shade. Tried building it again - no luck. Then, I found a website that told me to run "mvn clean package." No manifest file when running. Then, found another website and copy pasted some other stuff to delcare the main class (since that's basically all my manifest did anyways).